# MS Excel - How to drop the character between the concatenated cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to concatenated cells and put a comma between them. But some cells in the concatenated columns are empty and the result shows the commas between them. How to drop the commas if a cell is empty? 
Here's an image: 
[image]

and here's [the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTc-2sG0h1MaPuSANISk8BtTGZ9Ba6Pr/view?usp=sharing) to the above image spreadsheet.

Comment: If you were using excel 2016 or newer the function `TEXTJOIN()` is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution by VBA function:

```vba
Function join_ignore_empty(Src As Range) As String
Dim OneCell As Range, tmp As String
For Each OneCell In Src
    If Not CStr(OneCell.Value) = "" Then
        tmp = tmp & "," & CStr(OneCell.Value)
    End If
Next
If tmp <> "" Then
    join_ignore_empty = Mid(tmp, 2)
End If
End Function
```

and

```
F1="This is the concatenated text: "&join_ignore_empty(A1:D1)
```

---

---

Solution by formula:

```vba
F1="This is the concatenated text: "&A1&IF(AND(A1<>"",B1&C1&D1<>""),",","")&B1&IF(AND(B1<>"",C1&D1<>""),",","")&C1&IF(AND(C1<>"",D1<>""),",","")&D1
```

Logic: comma needed when both previous cell value and at least one of next values (concatenated value checked) are not empty.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I don't code VBA but I know how to run the code. 
Apparently I have to put the code in a
 "Sub abc()"; but when I do, it throws me a "Compile Error" saying "expected "End Sub". 
However, I've put the code in the proper Sub with an "End Sub". 
BTW, I put the formula in F1 as well. 
Any idea why?

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi For VBA part - create new module and insert the code into it. No additional symbols needed (your *I have to put the code in a "Sub abc()"* is wrong). For formula part - you may use it INSTEAD OF VBA code, not together or in addition.

Comment: The formula works perfect but as for the VBA code, when I insert the code to the created module and run it by pressing F5, I get asked to create a macro and when I do it automatically inserts a `Sub abc() ..... End Sub` to the VBA pane showing that the code must be inserted in between them and the rest is as explained in the previous comment.

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi *when I insert the code to the created module and run it by pressing F5* Please read ALL, not first line only! The *and `F1="This is the concatenated text: "&join_ignore_empty(A1:D1)`* means "set the formula `="This is the concatenated text: "&join_ignore_empty(A1:D1)` to the cell F1".

Comment: My bad. Your code worked a treat. Thanks a ton for your timely responses.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data starts in A1, and it only has 4 columns of data, as in the example,

Use:

```
=A1&IF(B1="","",",")&B1&IF(C1="","",",")&C1&IF(D1="","",",")&D1
```

And drag down

**Edit as per comment from Akina (thanks)**

```
=MID(A1&IF(B1="","",",")&B1&IF(C1="","",",")&C1&IF(D1="","",",")&D1,2,10000)
```

Comment: Wrong. Assume A1 is empty...

Comment: @Akina Why (i can only base my answer on the example data set, which does not show any headers)

Comment: If A1 is empty whereas at least one another cell contains any value, then excess leading comma will be added. See "formula" part of my answer.

Comment: @Akina good point ! ive added an edit to include this

Comment: Edited formula deletes 1st char from A1 value if it is not empty. Create a worksheet with all 16 possible variants (from all cells empty to all cells filled) and check.